# How to pass variable from model to controller in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Here I need show the count of DB table rows on my front page. I was done the count in my model page using count(). And i pass it a variable. Now I need to know how to pass the variable from model to controller.

Model:

```
 public static function count_product()
    {
     $n = DB::table('le_product')->where('le_product.status','=',1)->get();
     $n->count();   
    }
```

Contrller:

```
public function siteadmin_dashboard()
{

    $count = Count_model::count_product();      
    return view('siteadmin.admin_dashboard',['count' => $count]);
}
```

View:

```
    <div class="inner">
            <?php
              foreach ($count as $roww) 
              {
               // $ca=$roww->product_title;
                $n=count($roww);
            ?>
              <h3>{{$n}}</h3>

              <?php }

              ?>
              <p>Active Product</p>
            </div>
```

What i wrong in above code.

Comment: i am not a laravel developer. Since it looks like you should return a count from you model like

    {return $n->count();}

Comment: Its Okay. I done it in my view file

Comment: Yeah, return your value in the model and also you don't need a foreach in your view since the count number is a single variable.